# Identify SMD chip on a buck voltage regulator. Top marking DKAA6 or 1AGCN

Tags: power-supply, identification, surface-mount

I would like to get the chip part number, to get specifications, for a buck 5V regulator module. I have searched the letters and numbers on the chips (DKAA6 or 1AGCN), but no other reference could be found. These two codes can be found on two different boards, of identical design. Sellers of these are not responding to this question, or say they don't know.

[image: photo of PCB]

How could I find out what this is?

image [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09P7TJJGT)

Comment: The two top markings DKAA6 & 1AGCN, can be found on two different boards, of identical design. We had purchased a batch months ago advertised as 28V maximum input(1AGCN).  Now going to reorder, we find ( DKAA6 and 1AGCN) advertised as 20V max input.  We have tested the 1AGCNs for weeks under a continuous load of <100ma, with up to 29V input, with no failure or excess temperature measured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this thread on EEVblog forums:

https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/has-anyone-tried-this-buck-converter-board-42-cents-each/

Although the AliExpress link it gives seems to be dead (so I can't confirm by comparing PCB photos) the specs mentioned in the Amazon page linked in this question here and those in that EEVblog forum thread, seem to be the same.

EEVblog forum user *[floobydust](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/profile/?u=116400)* identified the IC as the Monolithic Power Systems [MP2315](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/mp2315.html) ("High Efficiency 3A, 24V, 500kHz, with AAM (light load mode), Synchronous Step Down Converter in TSOT23-8"). Its [datasheet](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2315/document_id/513/) says that its top marking will include AGC.

[image: excerpt from MP2315 datasheet mentioning top mark AGC]

So that may be an identification for the ICs you have marked 1AGCN. However I suspect the ICs you have which are marked DKAA6 are a different IC (even if they are pin-compatible).

It's impossible to see the PCB tracks in the photo here, but now using the datasheet details & application circuits, you can check whether the PCBs you have do match the details in that MP2315 datasheet.

---

It is worth reading that whole linked [EEVblog page above](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/has-anyone-tried-this-buck-converter-board-42-cents-each/), as it mentions several problems that users there have seen with those boards, for example:

- problems with output when using the "fixed voltage value" links on the PCB, either general voltage accuracy issues or definite wrong feedback resistors leading to totally wrong output voltages;
- the need for extra capacitance, especially on the output;
- the advertised 3A output current capability being unrealistic etc.

Answer (score 1):

The regulator marked DKAA6 is probably a [Rychip RY7135/RY7135C](https://semic-boutique.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/RY7135C-Datasheet-V1.0.1.pdf) or [HMSEMI HM2235/HM2235H](https://www.hmsemi.com/index.php/Down/down/id/1065.html).

[image]

I found this information in a thread on [mikrocontroller.net](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/543997) where people describe bad performance of boards with the DK* regulator.

[image]

(Source: [mikrocontroller.net](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/543997))